# Build html in server and bind to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some table that ng-repeat is building. the table contains a lot of data, and sometimes the build phase of the html is taking 10-20 seconds on weak computers.

So i've started to explore about building the html in the server, but the problem is that i'll loose the data-binding, and i'm needing it because i have inline edit functionality in the table.

The ultimate solution will be rendering the table in the server-side, with all the directives remaining including the ng-repeat, and on the client, makes the ng-repeat recognize that the html already has been rendered for the first time and not render it again, until the first change in the data.

In the Angular source code in the ngRepeatDirective, there is the "lastBlockMap" object that contain mapping betwee each element created by ng-repeat, to his scope, in that structure :

```
clone: [THE_ELEMET]
id: "005"
scope: ChildScope
```

and from reading this arcticle :
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-Rendering-DOM-Elements-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS.htm

i've got to conclusion that if i'll create this object, and pass it somehow to the ng-repaat directive, the directive will know that the html is already been rendered and will not render it again.

The problem is how to pass such information to ng-repeat???
Any one encountered this situation??

P.S.
I'm familiar with all the "ngRepeat preformance" posts and arcticles and have tried a lot of other options before approaching this solution, so please try to help me with this one.

Second P.S.
Sorry for my english... :)

Comment: have you considered pagination?

Comment: Not sure why do you think your problem is client rendering and why server side rendering (and delievering huge amount of data) would have better performance.Did you actually profile the specific use case for the cause of the performance hit/

Comment: yes, i've considered pagination and lazy loading, but my requirements forcing me to load all the data.

Comment: What it could be if not the DOM rendering?
i have big data, but not so big that calculations on him will cause 10-20 seconds of freeze..
on the other hand, with this data i'm building about 40 tables to represent this data..
Believe me that i've checked it from every direction before posted this question..

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for compile the html into loop in angular.

maybe you need to try clean the json data you try to render and make it as simple as you can, and if you include directive inside the table, try to render it after the table is done.

also, try to isolate the reason for the slowness, disable the inline edit and all the other featers inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use prerender.io to render the html on the server side. It basically opens a phantomjs process and executes the JS on the server, and serves the output. Works pretty well.